# Why the EN_PROTECT notification message is not sent to the RichEdit?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

Using a runtime created `TRichEdit` descendant, I need to be notified when the [`EN_PROTECTED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/richedit/ns-richedit-enprotected) notification message is sent to the RichEdit.

As far as I know, it should be sent to the RichEdit wrapping any notification message who could edit a protected part of the text (for example: `WM_PASTE`) and the original notification message code should be available in `TWMNotifyRE.ENProtected.msg`.

Unfortunately, it seems that my RichEdit never receives the `EN_PROTECTED` notification message.

Code sample:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Vcl.ComCtrls, Winapi.RichEdit, System.UITypes, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TMyRichEdit = class(Vcl.ComCtrls.TRichEdit)
  private
    procedure CNNotify(var AMessage: TWMNotifyRE); message CN_NOTIFY;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TMyRichEdit.CNNotify(var AMessage: TWMNotifyRE);
begin
  if (AMessage.NMHdr.code = EN_PROTECTED) then
  begin
    //this code is never executed
    DoSometing();
  end else
  begin
    inherited;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  RichEdit : TMyRichEdit;
begin
  RichEdit := TMyRichEdit.Create(Self);
  RichEdit.Align := alClient;
  RichEdit.Parent := Self;
  RichEdit.ScrollBars := ssVertical;
  RichEdit.DefAttributes.Protected := True;
end;

end.
```

I've [read](https://pastebin.com/JPH8r8x1) that the `DefAttributes.Protected` must be set to `True` in order to get the `EN_PROTECTED` notification but it doesn't solved the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in `DefAttributes` implementation. It ignores any changes to it, if its `TRichEdit` control window handle hasn't been allocated yet.

To fix that you can force allocating the handle before changing the `DefAttributes`:

```
RichEdit.HandleNeeded;
RichEdit.DefAttributes.Protected := True;
```

When you put `TRichEdit` on the form in design-time, the designer initializes its `Lines` property to `'RichEdit1'` or whatever, which will cause implicit handle allocation when loading the control from DFM. That would explain the difference between designer-created and manually-created control behavior.

Comment: I haven't looked at the implementation yet, but I would expect it to remember the assigned value and apply it to a new window when it is created at a later time. Most properties do that. If not, then I would consider this a bug that should be reported to Embarcadero

Comment: Private `TTextAttributes.SetAttributes` method is called within `TWinControl.CreateWnd` on for font related properties of `DefAttributes`. This is because this is because `CreateWnd` method calls `Perform(WM_SETFONT, FFont.Handle, 1);` which in turn invokes `TCustomRichEdit.WMSetFont` and that assigns the font to `DefAttributes`.  This initializes some of the char-format values of rich edit control like color, font name, font size, ... (see `TTextAttributes.SetAttributes`) but not value of `Protected`.